# How to isolate data from Vue component in JS class?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a simple JS class where in the constructor I initialize dictionary. I have methods to update or delete items from this dictionary.

```
export default class Items {
    constructor() {
        this.items = {};
        //Code that adds some values to it
    }
    save(item) {
        this.items[item.id] = item;
    }
    delete(itemId) {
        delete this.items[itemId];
    }
}
```

And I have a Vue component where I simply output values from this dictionary with

```
<p v-for="item in items">{{item}}</p>
```

In mounted method, I create `Items` object and assign `items` dictionary to variable `items` from Vue data. And from Vue I call methods save or delete, I see that dictionary `items` in Vue data is being changed, but UI doesn't get updated. I know that I can use `Vue.$delete` or `Vue.$set` but is it possible to isolate simple JS class from Vue and keep all the data in JS class?

I'm using Vue 2.4.4

Comment: I'm not sure if you can iterate over an object like that using `v-for`. Have you tried `<p v-for="itemKey in Object.keys(items)">{{items[itemKey]}}</p>`?

Comment: @sklingler93, yes I can. It works

Comment: I can't think of a way to make this reactive with Vue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use power of `VueJs`

```
...

    save(item) {

        Vue.set(this.items, item.id, item);

    }

    delete(itemId) {

    let index = this.items.findIndex(p => p.id === itemId);
    Vue.delete(this.items, index);

    }
```

Comment: but is it possible to not mix classic JS and Vue?

Comment: Yes sure VueJS is written by javascript

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to not let Vue keep the data? It will be able to monitor it to make the most effective dom changes that way. So in proper Vue style, you should move the class logic to the component level so that that data returns the items dictionary. Then attach the save and delete as methods for the component.

For objects you only get reactivity when you edit keys that existed at render time, otherwise, you need to alert Vue a key is being added. This is done with `Vue.set(this.items, item.id, item);`.

If you want to separate the logic from the component you can look into vuex which allows you to create modules of state and mutations.